# how to calculate cumulative salary in hive

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive

as hive only support subqueries in from cluase like select *from (subquery) and also support only equjoin so how can We calculate cumulative salary from a table like
table employee have records as below.

```
id     name       salary
e001  manish      10000
e002  amit         40000
e003  santosh     45000
e004  rohit       30000
```

so output should be like below

```
id       name           salary        cumsalary
e001     manish         10000          10000
e002     amit           40000          50000
e003     santosh        45000          95000
e004     rohit           30000         125000
```

how can I achive this in hive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hive supports the `sum()` analytic function, so you should be able to do the follwing:

```
select t1.* ,
sum(salary) over (order by id) cumsalary
from table t1
```

For more info about Hive's analytic functions see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

Answer (score 1):

Use `Correlated Sub-Query` to Find Cumulative Sum

```
 create table #temp(id varchar(10),    name  varchar(50),     salary int)
 insert #temp values 
('e001',  'manish',      10000),
('e002',  'amit   ',      40000),
('e003',  'santosh ',    45000),
('e004',  'rohit  ',     30000)

SELECT *,
       (SELECT Sum(salary)
        FROM   #temp t2
        WHERE  t2.id <= t.id) As cumsalary
FROM   #temp t
```